# UIStoryboardScene deallocates its controller unexpectedly without changing retain count

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am running unit tests against my view controllers. There are two view controllers in this suite, one of them has a segue to the other in the storyboard file.

In tests for both controllers, I create my test subject in same way: i get a `storyboard` with `storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:` (Typhoon for dependency injection uses the factory thing). Then, I use `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to get the VC.

In tests for my first view controller, all tests pass. Importantly, the view controller's `deinit` method is called ONLY when the vc itself goes out of scope in the test cases, or a new instance becomes the subject and the old one has its retain count reduced to 0.

however, in tests for the second VC, the tests fail in either of these cases (the VC goes out of scope or a new one becomes the subject) because for some reason there is a call being made to `[UIStoryboardScene dealloc]` which in turn calls `deinit` on the controller, even though its retain count should still be 1 (retained by the test case). ARC sends another release message to the VC when I set a new instance as the subject, and I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE=i386, GPFLT)`.

The `[UIStoryboardScene dealloc]` happens in a bunch of compiled code in XCTest framework (copied here), but I believe it's happening because the test case is ending, even though it shouldn't.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x57cf91, 0x00000001089953a3 sbprod`Mode2ViewController.__deallocating_deinit(self=0x00007fd2bbdde5d0) + 19 at Mode2ViewController.swift:68, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
* frame #0: 0x00000001089953a3 sbprod`Mode2ViewController.__deallocating_deinit(self=0x00007fd2bbdde5d0) + 19 at Mode2ViewController.swift:68
frame #1: 0x0000000108995492 sbprod`@objc Mode2ViewController.__deallocating_deinit + 34 at Mode2ViewController.swift:0
frame #2: 0x000000010a1ff702 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardScene dealloc] + 36
frame #3: 0x000000010b04dafe libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 232
frame #4: 0x000000010b04e0b8 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 488
frame #5: 0x0000000115841f37 XCTest`__24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2 + 430
frame #6: 0x0000000115876613 XCTest`-[XCTestContext performInScope:] + 190
frame #7: 0x0000000115841d78 XCTest`-[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 169
frame #8: 0x00000001158423a2 XCTest`-[XCTestCase performTest:] + 459
frame #9: 0x000000011583fcf7 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 396
frame #10: 0x000000011583fcf7 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 396
frame #11: 0x000000011583fcf7 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 396
frame #12: 0x000000011582cb10 XCTest`__25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke + 51
frame #13: 0x000000011584db4c XCTest`-[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 640
frame #14: 0x000000011582ca55 XCTest`-[XCTestDriver _runSuite] + 453
frame #15: 0x000000011582d7d1 XCTest`-[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] + 259
frame #16: 0x0000000115877a9a XCTest`_XCTestMain + 628
```

So:

1. Why is the UIStoryboardScene being created at all? I don't want a scene, just a VC, for my tests. It doesn't appear to happen in the previous test case. I think the only differences as far as the storyboard cares between the two VCs is that one of them has a segue into it, and the other out of it.
2. If the UIStoryboardScene is in fact existing in both cases, why is it `deinit`ing my VC before it ought to?
3. My test cases are also not very different from one another in scope, however this test case passes some closures to places and I'm not 100% on how closures affect ARC.

---

**EDIT**: relevant code shown here.

In my test case, which is made using Quick:

```
override func spec() {

    var subject: Mode2ViewController!

    let presentDisplayString = "DesiredString"

    describe("Mode2ViewController") {
        describe("loading") {
            describe("date and location") {
                context("when location is available") {
                    beforeEach {
                        let system = MockSystemComponents.CreateWith(location: true, groups: nil)

                        let assembly = ApplicationAssembly().activateWithCollaboratingAssemblies([
                                system
                            ])

                       //crash occurs on next line, before the 2nd test case, because the 
                       //old subject has already been deallocated (by UIStoryboardScene)
                       //but reassigning this var, which had retains it, triggers a release

                        subject = assembly.mode2ViewController() as! Mode2ViewController
                        let _ = subject.view
                    }

                    it("records the location") {
                        expect(subject).notTo(beNil())
                    }

                    it("displays the location as a meaningful string") {
                        expect(subject.locationLabel.text).to(equal(presentDisplayString))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the stack trace given above (first edit) is from a breakpoint I inserted in `Mode2ViewController.deinit()`.

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Comment: @jtbandes i've added the code which calls the 2nd (crashing) release. let me know if you need other pieces of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was that objective c treats things which begin with the keyword `new` differently with regards to their retain count. Typhoon can't handle methods that begin with `new` for this reason (see [issue](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/346)).

Solution: rename my typhoon method and the object being generated has the correct retain count.